# Changing all values under my parameter with NA in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame of dim `113x159`, like this:

```
 i1 i2 i3 i4 
1 49 76 3  65
2 35 14 37 98 
3 90 17 71 27 
4 27 65 54 88
```

I need to change all values < 20 to `NA`, like this:

```
 i1 i2 i3 i4 
 1 49 76 NA 65
 2 35 NA 37 98 
 3 90 NA 71 27 
 4 27 65 54 88
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use this `is.na(df) <- df < 20`.

Comment: Or, `df[df < 20] <- NA`

Comment: I've done it, it says: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors. It's probably due to columns/row names? Thank you!

Comment: This warning is because some of your columns are not numeric. In that case, you can include an `sapply` on both sides to only include numeric variables. `is.na(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)]) <- df[sapply(df, is.numeric)] < 20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your example, which consists of all numeric columns.

```
is.na(df) <- df < 20

df
  i1 i2 i3 i4
1 49 76 NA 65
2 35 NA 37 98
3 90 NA 71 27
4 27 65 54 88
```

In the case of your real dataset, it appears that you have factor columns. In that instance, you should use `sapply` to check the type of each column and only perform the replacement on numeric columns. This will work

```
is.na(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)]) <- df[sapply(df, is.numeric)] < 20
```

and also works in your example.

*warning:*
The less than operator, `<`, works to compare characters but they return FALSE for `<`

```
"t" < 20
[1] FALSE
"t" < 2000000000000
[1] FALSE
```

and TRUE for `>`

```
"t" > 2000000000000
[1] TRUE
```